# Calling matlab into java using matlabcontrol

Tags: javascript, matlab, jakarta-ee, matlab-deployment

I have my image processing functions in matlab and I want to call them into java using matlabcontrol. And so, I want to write a java servlet that uses matlabcontrol to call matlab.

I have of recent tried to write a java main application that can call matlab functions but am still confused on how to write a servlet of that kind. Please if anyone has some clues at least a few guidelines help me.